# how to split data using chi-square in R ( i have attributes of 6631)

Tags: r, statistics, feature-selection

```
weights<-chi.squared(Class~.,traindata)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 167.8 Mb
```

So i use

```
weights<-chi.squared(Class~.,traindata[1:1000])
```

this gives result for 999 attributes

```
weights<-chi.squared(Class~.,traindata[1000:2000])

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Class' not found
```

How can I get all the attributes by splitting the data. I am using 32 bits OS so it's impossible to get the attributes at a time.

Answer (score 0):

When you subset your data using:

```
traindata[1000:2000]
```

It looks like the column `Class` must be in the first 1,000 columns of `traindata`. Thus your call to `chi.squared()` is complaining about missing that column. You just need to make sure you include `Class` in every subset you pass through `chi.squared()`. For example:

```
class_col <- which(names(traindata) == 'Class')
weights <- chi.squared(Class ~ . , traindata[union(class_col, 1000:2000)])
```

That will record the index number of the `Class` column and make sure it's included in your subset.

Comment: it works but after spliting the data when i am predictin the data it isn't working > pred<-predict(c,traindata)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 98.7 Mb

Comment: You're just running out of memory. Try removing objects you no longer need with rm() and/or doing whatever you're trying to do on a smaller subset of your data. If that doesn't work you may just not have enough RAM for this task.